# How do I make Java's `System.out.println()` write to ubuntu's stdout?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I wrote this tiny java program to learn how jar file works on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

I made the jar file using the following commands

```
javac Hello.java
jar cfe Hello.jar Hello Hello.class
```

and then I ran this command and I got what I expected

```
$ java -jar Hello.jar
Hello, world!
```

However, when I put the command in crontab

```
12 19 22 5 1 java -jar /home/ubuntu/Hello.jar
```

no output was given, which seems to indicate Java's `System.out.println()` doesn't write to ubuntu's stdout. So, how do I make Java's `System.out.println()` write to ubuntu's stdout?

Comment: Your first test case indicates that java - or rather the JVM - does indeed write to the standard output. The question is therefore centered around crontab, not java, and thus off-topic for StackOverflow. It might be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I wonder what is stdout for jobs running by cron? (background)  (just a Java developer asking) - OK, found it - `MAILTO` env-var or `-s` option - is one of this being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
12 19 22 5 1 java -jar /home/ubuntu/Hello.jar >> path/to/some/log.txt
```

The question does not have anything to do with java though. and might therefore be counted as off-topic.
It has to do with crontab and shell...

Comment: Thank you. That command does work though, it doesn't seem to use stdout directly,  `>>` means redirect, right?

Comment: Yes. a cronjob runs a job in the "background". If you want to make the output available you can redirect it to a file and read that. The Hello.jar is printing to stdout but the background job is not showing it in the foreground...

Comment: @user15793316 thank you. By "syslog", you mean `/var/log/syslog`, right?